# Glide is showing error while building app

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-glide

First I tried to update glide to 4.6.0 but it had some errors then I decided to downgrade it to 4.4.0 but now it's even not building the app. I tried to search a lot of questions both in `SO` and in `github` but I couldn't find any . Please help to fix my error.

Error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
```

> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Srinu\Infinity\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Srinu.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.bumptech.glide\glide\4.4.0\7d55ca453af56b7f7e6b494c1781755d89047d4f\glide-4.4.0.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [glide-4.4.0.jar:com/bumptech/glide/util/Synthetic.class]))

Gradle Dependencies:

```
     compile('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;//I saw this in a question but even it couldn't solve the 
    issue
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.4.0'
```

Comment: Try Build>Clean project

Comment: I've cleaned it at least for 5 times till now but error is not gone

Comment: Have you got any jars in /libs folder?

Comment: @shmakova yes I had one now I've deleted it

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Try to remove compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.4.0'

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti sir even after removing that error was coming but after removing **@aar** my error is gone but could you please elaborate where the error was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after a lot of try I tried a different approach and it solved my issue.
I just removed `'@aar'`from dependency and `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.4.0'` my glide is working fine .But I wonder where the error was I seriously couldn't figure out the real issue.

So now the final gradle is :

```
compile('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0') {
    transitive = true;
}
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since glide is a big library, while adding glide the number of methods increases above 64k (1 Dex). Hence you need to add Multidex support in your gradle. Have a look at his for how to do.

[Enable Multidex for Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: Thank for your attention but I've tried it already but it couldn't solve my error

Comment: have you removed all jar files ?

Comment: yes I did but that wasn't helpful but please do check my own answer to the question